# Has Full Metal Alchemist Brotherhood always been the number 1 top anime on MyAnimeList?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood, myanimelist

I would like to know if there were animes which reigned supreme on MAL before and after FMAB made its entry on the list. Has any anime ever dethroned FMAB (even if temporarily) or has it always been the defending champion, to this date.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: IIRC, Inuyasha beat FMA:B out for like a week or so but was returned to a lower position shortly thereafter. I'm not 100% certain on which show it was, but I do remember at least at one point FMA:B was beat.

Answer (score 6):

In July 2022, *FMA:B* was overtaken by *Kaguya-sama: Love is War - Ultra Romantic*, the third season of *Kaguya-sama*. By October 2022 it had regained its #1 spot.

[image]

In April 2023 [it was overtaken by *Oshi no Ko*](https://www.animesenpai.net/oshi-no-ko-anime-dethroned-from-its-top-ranking), but gained #1 back again the following month.

In November 2023, it was dethroned again by *Frieren: Beyond Journey's End*. As of March 2024, *Frieren* remains at #1 - I'm uncertain whether it's been #1 the whole time, though.

[image]

I've heard that *Bleach: The Thousand-Year Blood War* and *Chainsaw Man* also briefly overtook *FMA:B*, but haven't been able to confirm it.

Comment: I heard some immature FMAB peeps might be 1 star brigading Kaguya s3 just so FMAB can go back to the top. Ever heard anything like this?

Comment: I haven't, but I wouldn't be surprised, as I know similar incidents have happened before on MAL and other rankings sites. If it *is* happening, it will likely be reversed.

Comment: @BCLC I don't follow MAL regularly but AFAIK from my previous outings, FMAB used to be #1 at ranking for many years and folks there do not like it to be dethroned. Whenever a hype anime is released,  it became #1 even though only 1 episode was released. This happed with Kaguyasama S3. As the show progressed, it dropped and FMAB became #1. Vote brigading and bots helped that. Same case with Chainsaw Man. When it is released, it was 9.03, now it is 8.98. This is enough evidence that MAL is infested with bots and spams. Bottom line, MAL ratings is not accurate.

Comment: Also FWIW, the current FMAB ratings is 9.12 (dropped from 9.16)

Answer (score 4):

On this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/2pb8tq/myanimelist_top_anime_list_evolution_since_2007/), you can see state of top anime list since 2007 until 2016. According to it, FMA: Brotherhood was outscored by Gintama at least for some period of time.

This history thread is not up to date, but at least it answers your question - yes, there was another top anime since FMA:B was released.

Answer (score 3):

As of writing this answer, [Gintama: The Final](https://myanimelist.net/anime/39486/Gintama__The_Final) has surpassed FMAB to be the #1 rank on MAL.

[image]

Also, [Fruits Basket: The Final](https://myanimelist.net/anime/42938/Fruits_Basket__The_Final?q=fruit&cat=anime) was ranked #1 on MAL for a short period of time. It was also a matter of heated discussion on MAL for reasons I won't get into.

[image]